# How to show all value of a single column into a single row in pl/sql report?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to show a single column into a single row in pl/sql report. i want to do

```
    item
    -----
    itme1
    item2
    item4
    item5
```

to

```
    item
    -----
    item1,item2,item3, item4, item5
```

I have used the following code

```
function CF_hs_descFormula return Char is
v_items varchar2(600);
begin
v_items:=:hs_desc;
if v_items is not null then
   v_items:=v_items||',';

end if;
return v_items;
end;
```

but it is not working.  Please tell me how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LISTAGG` in oracle:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(name, ', ')
     WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name) "name_list"
FROM TABLE1;
```

Comment: i want to do this for pl/sql report. Is it possible for repost? @Hamidreza